# Require socket server into controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So basically im trying to setup my node(express) project with a MVC structure. The problem is when i need to require an instance of a socket in any of my controllers as i always get undefined. Any idea how to improve this code?

// server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var socketio = require('socket.io');

var homeController = require('./controllers/home');

var app = express();

app.post('/api/chat/messages/:room', homeController.postChatMessages);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

var io = socketio.listen(server);

module.exports = io;
```

// Controller home.js

```
var io = require('../server');
var Chat = require('../models/chat');

console.log(io); //GET UNDEFINED

exports.postChatMessages = function(req, res) {
Chat.findOne({ name: req.params.room }, function(err, chat) {
    if (chat) {
        chat.users._id = req.user;
        chat.messages.push({
            text: req.body.message
        });

        chat.save(function(err, saved) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
                return console.log(err);
            }
            res.send(saved);
            io.sockets.emit('receiveMessage', saved);
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'This chat room is not registered or maybe is not active.' });
    }
});
};
```

Comment: your server file is called app.js and you are doing a require on /server in the controller :/

Comment: don't you have to set the port first to do a get('port)'?                                    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to pass your controller the right object. you are creating a new object so you dont have the right reference. There are some possibilities for this, I will show you only one... I could not test the code, but I guess you got the idea. good luck

in app.js

```
var homeController = require('./controllers/home')(io);
```

in home.js you have to do some more work:

```
var HomeController = function(io){
  this.postChatMessages = function(req, res) {
    Chat.findOne({ name: req.params.room }, function(err, chat) {
      if (chat) {
        chat.users._id = req.user;
        chat.messages.push({
          text: req.body.message
        });

        chat.save(function(err, saved) {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
            return console.log(err);
          }
          res.send(saved);
          io.sockets.emit('receiveMessage', saved);
        });
      }else{
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'This chat room is not registered or maybe is not active.' });
      }
    });
  };
}

module.exports = function(io){
  return new HomeController(io);
}
```

Comment: Awesome.. this makes much more sense!!